# How do i implement remote validation in kendoUI grid using angular js and web api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I need to insert a product into a sql table.I'm using kendo UI grid and angular js.
How do i validate if the product is already there in the database before inserting it.Database access is using webApi method?
can anyone helps here?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

One option (that may not fit your requirement) would be to expose a Upsert method (you would typically do this with the PUT verb).  Then, if it doesn't exist, it would create it.  If it does, it would update it.

However, if you want to perform a POST and receive and error for existing records, a typical response would be 400 - bad request.  It isn't clear what you are using on the server-side.  If you are using ASP.NET Web API, this would result in an invalid model state and return a BadRequest (400).

Comment: I'm using asp.net wep api methods. can i call a function in the Schema of kendoUIgrid  like.....ProductName: {
                         editable: true,
                         validation: {
                             required: true,

                             /*
                             productNameValidation: function (input) {

Comment: You seem a bit confused about client-side vs. server-side operations.  Your code snippet looks like a kendo column specification.  So, the validation function would be a javascript function that runs on the client.  I suppose it could make an ajax call to the server, if necessary.  So, your api could expose a ProductExists() method that could be checked.  However, a more typical approach would be to wire up your grid datasource to a create (POST) method and handle the error (400) that it might return when actually trying to create the entity.